# The Hashrate of the Raspberry Pi 2 and 3

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, performance, cryptocurrency

I've been searching for a definitive answer to the above question, but somehow only seem to find semi-true statements (according to replies to these statements), or very outdated answers (for example this question on the [Bitcoin SE](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3165/what-hash-rate-can-a-raspberry-pi-achieve-can-the-gpu-be-used)).

So I hope you can help me out here:

What is the achievable hashrate of the Raspberry Pi 2 and Raspberry Pi 3?

Clarification:
I do not want to know if it's feasible to mine using the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but I am sure if you do few minutes of searching on the internet you will find it, and *it sucks*.  AFAIK people who have gone down this road have in the end discovered despite the relatively low power profile of the pi, it's still likely to cost more in electricity than you will make via mining.  Get an FPGA and a pile of textbooks, lol, and you could use a pi to drive that for very fast hashing.

Comment: The 'few minutes of research' were done - however, as I stated above, the posts are old; from around 2013 mostly, and on the old RPi models. There are posts like [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/comments/33iz4h/mining_on_raspberry_pi_2/) which are new-ish, but they do not answer the question Im asking above: how much hashrate does it have?

Comment: I don't know enough about the topic to tell you whether or not the SoC really has hardware provision for hashing in this context (like I said I don't have an answer), but either way, I would assume at best you could take the "it sucks" number and do a litttle multiplication based on clock speed and number of cores and get a number that "sucks less".  Bitcoin.SE might be a better place to at least get some of the required details straight first.

Comment: Put bluntly:  You might as well use a smartphone (although of course the pi cost less, I think it will be equally pointless).

Comment: While I can't give you an exact number, we can logically assume that using an RPi (or even a whole army of them) is a useless endeavor. Even current generation models of i7 processors can't keep up with the specialized rigs that are now being built to do so. These rigs use specialized GPUs in tandem.

Comment: @j4ck I did the math with my original Pi approximately  a year ago, I wrote down the results, back then I assumed the Pi would be running 24/7 and would not be running anything else on It, and after miner fees I would be looking at 3.5 to 15 cents CAD, remember this isn't including the cost of electricity. Be sure to also factor in that last year it was a lot more profitable to mine bitcoins than it is today

Comment: Lads, I appreciate the heads up on how inefficent mining with a Pi is - but that wasn't my question.

Comment: Frustrating as it may be, it's likely that you'll never get an answer to your question without doing your own testing. It appears that mining with a Pi is about as sensible as trying to render an entire Pixar movie on one. With it being such a foregone conclusion nobody's likely to undertake the testing. I'm as curious as the next person though, so if you come up with a number it would be great to see it in an answer.

Comment: I have done extensive research on this. There are a few sites that give the formula. This is one of them  https://alloscomp.com/bitcoin/calculator. Only you can do the equation it is based on factors related to your equipment and electricity costs ect..I can tell you this also. At this point the equations are so complex you may want to concider joining a pool if your dead set on trying. Unfortunately I have no info on joining a pool.

Comment: For the people commenting on electricity costs, it's worth noting that this assumes paying for electricity by usage.  Flat rate electricity is not so uncommon and would negate that particular concern. That's not to say this is worthwhile - Just that emphasizing this particular argument doesn't seem particularly useful, especially since, as OP notes that wasn't his question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**My Raspberry Pi 3 Seemed to mine at about 400(ish) kilohashes per second**.

This is on Einsteinium with the algorithm called Scrypt. I am running a program called m-minerd and am mining on the pool emc2.suprnova.cc. I have set this program to mine on all four cores at 100 percent!

If you want a more profitable coin to mine try mining the Magi coin. The official website is [here](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXq4_xgbDYAhXDylQKHVC9CucQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.m-core.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw2Rh_goBUMj-7E5sKXDCiem). Magi is made to only be cpu mined and is more profitable for small devices. [Here](https://xmg.minerclaim.net/) is a good mining pool. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I'm running a Raspberry Pi 3B+ Monero miner 24/7 (no power costs so profitable more or less...)... I'm getting ~10H/s. Monero is CPU mineable so 10H/s isn't ver y bad at all... If I calculate my earnings on webpages like [this one](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/xmr) it seems like I would earn about 3.50$...

Hope I could help! :)

Comment: Either you are missing a k there, or mining difficulty increased dramatically since :-) Currently 10H/s  == 0.01kH/s which is 0.00003 XMR which is 0.004 $ / week at zero electricity/fees. I'm pretty certain ASIC miners dominate Monero based on what regular CPUs can achieve: https://news.bitcoin.com/report-claims-85-of-the-monero-network-dominated-by-asic-miners/ More specific Monero question at: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/could-i-use-a-raspberry-pi-to-mine-monero

Answer (score -3):

https://alloscomp.com/bitcoin/calculator. You will need to calculate that question yourself. The cost of mining and hash rate is unique to every miner. If this is endevor is a must for you I suggest you look at pooling if that is still an option. Keep in mind the calculations that are trying to be solved to actually get any bitcoin are very complex and take alot of power That needs to be apart of the equation. Join a bit coin forum they can help as most of the users are currently mining.

Comment: as stated before, I do not actually want to know how much a Pi can mine. In addition, this still requires knowing the actual hash rate of the Raspberry pi, which is what I wanted to know in the first place.