# Confused on how to increase speed of crypto mining (Raspberry Pi 3B+)

Tags: processor-speed, cryptocurrency

According to the [top answer on this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49552/the-hashrate-of-the-raspberry-pi-2-and-3), this guy is getting 400/KH per Pi. I'm getting something like 10. The command I'm running just includes the pool stratum, my worker name, and password. No other flags attached. How can I speed my Pi up?

(I use m-minerd as well, threads are at 4-the max, I think-and efficency is at 100)

Comment: Did you try exactly the way that post did to compare? You didn’t even mention what currency you’re mining.

Comment: it says that he seems to be getting 400 kh/s .... the word `seem` means that there is an uncertainty in the value

Comment: @jsotola I mean, the difference between 400 and 10 is a lot

Comment: @T.M. I was told that the crypto type didn't matter. I guess maybe they're wrong. I'm using Magi